# Remove exporting button in Internet Explorer alone

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts, export

Using offline exporting in highcharts which is not working in IE . I would like to remove the exporting button only in the Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that you have created your chart like;

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', { ............ });
```

Now you have a `chart` object which you can update later according to the result of IE detection.

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1))
{
  chart.update({
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
}
```

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4336116/)

Comment: Works fine when i added this script.